# How to create a list of File in Java?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, replace, hashmap

I am trying to create a list of files in Java where each file have an id, i am using a `HashMap`, then replace files in `ArrayList` by files in `HashMap` like this :

```
ArrayList<Object> tab = new ArrayList<>();
tab.addAll(Arrays.asList(par));//par contains files among objects 
File file = null;
HashMap<Integer, File> hm = new HashMap<>();
//loop start browsing tab for files
        file = new File(dir + fileName);                            
        hm.put(i, file);
//loop end
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, File> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
        tab.remove(entry.getKey());
        tab.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
 }
```

The problem is it doesnt replace it just add them and it's not adding an object. How to do this in the correct way ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If `tab` doesn't hold only `File` objects originally then wouldn't it be clearer to just use the `HashMap` you created for storing the files? That would also allow easily and efficiently accessing files by id.

Comment: @Mick But the ID appears to be an index of the list, so there's no benefit for a Map

Comment: Yes, currently it seems so. But for some reason OP decided to leave out relevant parts of the code so it's hard to say what the best solution would be. It would be essential to understand the original `tab` data structure and why this juggling is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to move all the `File` objects from the values `HashMap` to the `ArrayList<Object>` to an index of the key from the `HashMap`.

The interface `List` has a method `List::set(int index, E element)` which replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

```
List<Object> tab = new ArrayList<>();                  // I suggest you List<File>
// ...
HashMap<Integer, File> hm = new HashMap<>();
// ...      
hm.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> tab.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace list elements, don't remove anything, instead use

```
tab.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

Also, I think you want `ArrayList<File> tab`